# Function definition inside the if condition is not defined in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why does the following piece of code not define the dummy function?

```
if(function dummyFunction() {}){

}
console.log(dummyFunction); // Throws ReferenceError: dummyFunction is not defined
```

The reason why I ask is - had I defined it as following -

```
function dummyFunction(){}
console.log(dummyFunction); //This would have worked
```

BUT:

```
var xxx = function dummyFunction(){}
console.log(dummyFunction); //This would NOT have worked.
```

Somehow I feel that when I use it with `if` condition, it should have behaved like the first case and not the second. I fail to understand why without assignment to a variable (like in the second case) I am not able access the method via function name.

Update: I got to face this problem when I was solving a JS questionnaire.

Comment: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) may help explain. Function *Expressions* don't attach their name to the surrounding scope like *Declarations*.

Comment: Because that's a function expression, not a function definition.

Answer (score 4):

When you put the function definition in the `if()`, it's a *named function expression*. The scope of the name is just the body of the function, not the surrounding scope. It's analogous to:

```
var foo = function dummyFunction() {};
```

This defines `foo` in the outer scope, but `dummyFunction` is only defined in the body of the function.

I'm not sure why you're doing this, but the way to write it is:

```
if (var dummyFunction = function() {}) {
```

Comment: I would say there is no way to correctly write whatever it is OP is trying to do.

Comment: I don't get it why is it `named function expression`, is there some other place also where we observe the same kind of behavior?

Comment: It's a named function expression because it's a function expression and it has a name after the `function` keyword. The keyword `function` only starts a function **definition** if it's at the beginning of a statement.

Comment: Did you read the linked question, it explains all the different ways to define functions.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
var dummyFunction;
if(typeof dummyFunction !== 'Function'){
  dummyFunction = function(){}
}
```

Comment: using `typeof` may be neater